# Recording the time of the start of a screen touch in PsychoPy on Windows

Tags: python, windows, touchscreen, psychopy

I'm helping to implement an experiment using PsychoPy on a Windows 8 tablet. It doesn't seem to be possible to get direct access to touch events through either PsychoPy, or the pyglet or PyGame interfaces.

Most other sources I've found have referred to using mouse move events in place of touch events. This works fine for recording position, but for recording time it doesn't work for us. We would like to collect the timing of the start of the touch, whereas the mouse event comes at the end of the touch.

Does anyone know of a way to do this, either in PsychoPy or by importing another library into the experiment?

**Update**: Logging ioHub mouse events, it looks like press and release mouse events are both sent at the end of the touch. This makes sense as this is the point at which the OS is sure that the touch is not a swipe. (Also, it will decide whether the touch is a left- or right-click depending on the duration of the touch).

Comment: What are you using to record the mouse events... and can you change to something equivalent to `<Mouse1-Down>` rather than `<Mouse1-Click>` maybe?.

Comment: Have you looked at ``psychopy.iohub`` which explicitly differentiates between press and release events? There's a demo for elo touchscreens (Coder --> Demos --> ioHub --> elotouchscreen). If that doesn't work, maybe it registers as a mouse event in which case you also have press and release events separated (see Coder --> demos --> ioHub --> mouse). The demos are fairly complicated so let me know if they work and I can post a more explicit solution to your question.

Comment: @JonasLindeløv Thanks for this. The code is currently using pyglets mouse events via PsychoPy. A touch on the screen seems to correspond to a mouse *move*, not a *click*, so mouse down/up will likely not work -- I should investigate iohub events and see which ones are produced. I have looked at the ELO touchscreen code and it seems very different to our situation. It's a separate hardware device which has to be explicitly queried over an external port. We have a built-in screen which (via the OS) should already be producing WM_GESTURE / WM_TOUCH messages -- the question is how to get them!

Comment: Yes, get back when you have identified which iohub events are generated. Just do something like (1) ``from psychopy import iohub, core``, (2) ``io = iohub.launchHubServer()``, (3) ``core.wait(5)`` while doing stuff with the mouse, (4) ``print io.devices.mouse.getEvents()``

Comment: @JonasLindeløv I have added this to my original question, unfortunately it was as I suspected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed this using a hook into the WndProc, it's not pretty but it works. The solution, for posterity:

https://github.com/alisdt/pywmtouchhook

A brief summary:

I used a combination of ctypes and pywin32 (unfortunately neither alone could do the job) to register the target HWND to receive touch messages, and replace its WndProc, passing through all non-touch messages to the original WndProc.