# When running a VNC server, how can I distinguish between local input and remote mouse click events?

Tags: python, touch, remote-desktop, vnc, psychopy

I have a computer with a touchscreen where users navigate an interface presented by a Python app. This computer runs a VNC server (x11vnc on Debian). Administrators sometimes assist the users to navigate the interface remotely via VNC (RealVNC Viewer on MacOS), clicking their mouse on the appropriate interface components.

Our touchscreen GUI uses PsychoPy* to draw graphical elements and collect input data (where users are touching the screen, whether it is inside or outside of relevant hit boxes), but have no way to distinguish between user input (local) and administrator assistance input (remote).

Is it possible to distinguish between local touches and remote VNC mouse click events?

If so, what approaches are available to the Python app that is presenting the GUI?

** A scientific research library popular in psychology and behavioral science, which I believe uses Pygame and Pyglet.*

Comment: Would simply knowing if a VNC session is active be sufficient? My (admittedly not deep) understanding of VNC is that it attempts to not stray from controlling standard input devices to minimize compatibility problems or other wonky behavior.

Comment: @esqew no, in our case we have users on both the local (server) and remote (client) ends operating the touchscreen (local) or activating it remotely via a mouse click (remote). I am tasked with analyzing local user input, so am seeking to filter out input of remote origin.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind editing your question to add a few more details about the application itself (primarily what the GUI is written using), as well as how you’re collecting the metrics in question currently?

Comment: @esqew sure, done. We're currently only measuring whether a touch is within a hitbox or not, and recording the coordinates of that event, using PsychoPy's interface for this `psychopy.event.Mouse`: https://www.psychopy.org/api/event.html

Comment: Interesting - does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30850089/recording-the-time-of-the-start-of-a-screen-touch-in-psychopy-on-windows) by any chance answer your question? (TL;DR: The `pyglet` backend that `psychopy` uses to create windows doesn't expose very much in the way of touch vs. mouse events. However, it seems someone was able to hook a low-level API in Windows to retrieve the information on touch vs. mouse events.)

Comment: Ah nice find, thanks. This touchscreen runs on Debian so I don't believe this example could work for our purposes, as it seems to be Windows-specific.

Comment: Why not have a channel separate from the GUI through which test administrators can deliver commands?

Comment: @user3840170 this is an interesting proposition that we may explore. it would require listening for new events on a new channel, which may require more development and testing time than my group is willing to spend on this issue.